# set cursor to hand on empty image-control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml:

```
    <Border x:Name="brdImg3" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="10,5,5,5" Cursor="Hand">
        <Image x:Name="image3" Stretch="Fill" Cursor="Hand"/>
    </Border>
```

The problem is, that the Hand-Cursor is only shown when the Source of Image is not null. When the Source is null, the Hand-Cursor is only shown when the Mouse is over the border. I need showing the Hand-Cursor when the Mouse is in the Border. How can I do this?

Comment: Background=Transparent on your Border

Comment: This is the solution I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Converter in Cursor, check sources is null or empty. Logic is writen

```
Cursor={Binding Source,Converter={StaticResources CursorConverter}

 public class CursorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(value.Tostring()))
            {
                return Cursor.Hand;
            }
            else
            {
                return Cursor.Arrow;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```